# Liblinear on mac osx 10.9.3

Tags: matlab, mex, liblinear

Environment : Matlab R2014a (8.3), Macosx mavericks 10.9.3, Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)

I am compiling the liblinear package from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/. I fixed the mexopts.h in the matlab installation directory to point to right SDKROOT, C and CXX. When I run make from inside matlab under the director liblinear-1.94/matlab/, the libsvmread and libsvmwrite successfully generated the mexmaci64 library. However, it did not generate for train and predict. Hence I commented the try catch expection in the make, to understand the error. Now I getting the following error.

```
Error using mex  
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
"_daxpy_", referenced from:  
  TRON::tron(double*) in tron.o  
  TRON::trcg(double, double*, double*, double*) in tron.o  
"_ddot_", referenced from:  
  TRON::tron(double*) in tron.o
  TRON::trcg(double, double*, double*, double*) in tron.o
"_dnrm2_", referenced from:
  TRON::tron(double*) in tron.o
  TRON::trcg(double, double*, double*, double*) in tron.o
"_dscal_", referenced from:
  TRON::trcg(double, double*, double*, double*) in tron.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)


Error in make (line 16)
    mex CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=c99 -v" -largeArrayDims train.c
            linear_model_matlab.c ../linear.cpp ../tron.cpp
            "../blas/*.c"
```

Any idea why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the program is looking for the files in the blas folder.

I got the exact same error when trying to add liblinear manually to my c++ using cmake (with the new ranksvm- so I couldn't brew) . I solved this by adding the *.o AND the blas/*.o files as sources to my project.

...using this as an analogy perhaps you only included the liblinear folder and not the folder and all its contents in your Matlab project?

Answer (score 0):

## Dylib in x86_64

First of all, let's make sure that the liblinear (or whichever library that you are linking to) dylib is in x86_64, or at least universal (i386 + x86_64) format.

$ file /usr/local/Cellar/liblinear/1.94/lib/liblinear.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/liblinear/1.94/lib/liblinear.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

If you install your libraries via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), this should not be a problem.

## GNU Libtool

Another instance where I frequently see the `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` is when I compile node.js modules using GNU's libtool. If you install GNU Libtool, try uninstalling/unlinking it

Comment: When I checked the file on the library that offers these functionality, I get "blas.a: current ar archive random library". How I build it as Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64?